# How to store loaded pages from pagination and get loaded pages when redirecting back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i changed basic table pagination with numbering each page to infinite scroll way of pagination(clicking "Load More" adds data in table). I got stucked with issue when navigating to other page, and then coming back it calls first page again, so i have to click load more again and again instead of displaying last loaded page. Maybe my title is confusing, but i hope i explained you here

This is my code:

```
function pensPaginationChanged() {
        vm.errorPens = true;
        vm.currentPagePens++;
        vm.loadingPensTable = true
        getPens(true);
    }
function goToPage(page, pen) {
        localStorage.setItem('from_recipe', JSON.stringify({
            type: 'add'
        }));
        if (vm.feeding_methods) {
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.feeding_methods.length; i++) {
                if (vm.feeding_methods[i].selected) {
                    var fm = vm.feeding_methods[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        var mixer_wagons = [];
        if (vm.wagons) {
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.wagons.length; i++) {
                mixer_wagons.push(vm.wagons[i]);
            }
        }
        var data = {
            pens: vm.selected_pens,
            recipe_name: (vm.recipe && vm.recipe.recipe_name) ? vm.recipe.recipe_name : null,
            feeding_methods: fm,
            mixer_wagons: mixer_wagons,
            pens_page: vm.currentPagePens,
            ration: page == 'iManagement.addNewIngredient' ? vm.modalRation : vm.selectedRation,
            show_selector_dto: page == 'iManagement.addNewIngredient' ? vm.showSelectorDto : undefined,
            rations_page: page != 'rations.addnewration' ? vm.currentPageRation : undefined,
            ration_type: page != 'rations.addnewration' ? vm.selected_rations_type.value : undefined,
            original_ration: page == 'iManagement.addNewIngredient' ? vm.originalRation : undefined,
            page: page,
            event: vm.event
        }
        dataServiceFactory.add_new_recipe_data = data;
        $timeout(function () {
            $state.go(page, {
                uuid: pen && pen.id ? pen.id : null
            });
        }, 50)
    }
```

Function goToPage saves temporary data when navigating to other pages. But for **pens_page: vm.currentPagePens** it always sets page one by default when i redirect back to that page.
Any ideas for this? If you need more code i can provide. Thanks in advance

Comment: Store the current page somewhere and get it back on redirect. I don't know how you redirect the page. So if it's a complete redirect to another URL then store the current in "local storage" otherwise store it in a variable in the component.

Comment: Well i can make it load that last page loaded, but all previous pages are lost. So for example if i loaded 3 pages, then redirect and come back, only 3rd page will be show. But 1 and 2 are lost

Comment: @Javi-Bon then load all data from page 1 to the current page fix the promblem. doesn't it?

Comment: Thats where im stucked. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I can not provide you a practical solution because the code snippets that you have posted here are not clear. Could you please provide a more clear code with more details?